# What is "claustrophobic insularity"?

Tags: word-meaning, expressions

In [an article](https://www.quora.com/What-is-something-you-absolutely-despise-about-your-country), someone conveys their view of a country and mentions a property called *claustrophobic insularity*. I googled those word getting nothing useful.

I get that *claustrophobic* has to do with fear of enclosed spaces and *insularity* is preference for introversion of cultural focus. However, that specific combination tells me little and I definitely can't connect it by context to the properties of the considered country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Claustrophobic insularity" isn't really a known phrase, just two known words being used together. I think your understanding of the individual words isn't quite right.

**Insularity** doesn't really mean a *preference* for being insular. It implies an *ignorance* of or lack of interest in other cultures.

**Claustrophobia** is literally the fear of confined spaces but is sometimes also used in a figurative way to refer to other kinds of limitations. It is often used quite glibly by persons with no actual phobia to describe a cramped situation. "Claustrophobic" is sometimes used as an [adjective](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/claustrophobic) to describe a space that looks cramped.

It would seem a contradiction to say that someone is both insular *and* figurately claustrophobic - you cannot be afraid of something you are unaware (ignorant) of. I understand the phrase to be an insult - the writer is saying that from *their* point of view, another person's insularity looks figuratively claustrophobic. In other words, they would not like to live in the confines of ignorance. As an alternative, I might say they were "trapped inside their own tiny mind".

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit slow today. Would you be kind and suggest a different expression describing what your assumption tells you in regard to the original text poster's intention? I get it's prerogative but what exactly is his remark complaining about? What would be the opposite for this view? Open-mindedness?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I might say a person was trapped inside their own tiny mind.

Comment: It's fine (correct) to use claustrophobic to describe a place/situation (dictionaries even say it's fine in both American and British style English): https://www.dictionary.com/browse/claustrophobic https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/claustrophobic https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/claustrophobic https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/claustrophobic